# Bind a shotcut to temperature color adjusment (night mode activated)

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, brightness, monitor, night-light

I would like a hotkey/shotcut/keybinding to turn up or down the color temperature of the screen. Since I always have the night light mode enable but trough the day I just change it manually if I can't read properly something or watch an image etc. So it would be good to know how to. thanks in advance